# Is it ok to post an article on a subject and ask if it needs any corrections?

Tags: discussion, article

I wrote a brief essay (for no particular reason other than personal understanding) on the concept of multi-threaded applications. I myself am still getting familiar with the concept of threads, and wrote this as a way of taking notes to basically teach myself. In this paper, I explain a comparison between a "multi-threaded process" and a "multi-lane highway" where each lane is a thread, and each car is a line of code. I explain some scenarios in multi-threaded apps and how to relate to that scenario with the highway example.

Is this something I can post on StackOverflow and ask for corrections? I need to make sure I'm not making anything up here, and that I have the important topics covered. It's just one page in length - 4 paragraphs.

Comment: No, but you can ask *specific* questions about concepts you're not sure about, although such questions are probably better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't do proofreading of articles as Q&A, sorry.

If there's anything technical that you need to clarify, you can try to phrase it as a *question*, like any other programming question that you'd have.

As a quick example, you could ask along the lines of:

> Am I right to say that a multi-threaded process is like a multi-lane highway, where each lane is a thread and each car is a line of code? *[... elaborate on this comparison you're making, so on and so forth]*

Comment: -1, [proofreading is explicitly encouraged on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader).

Comment: @Popular Demand: Oh, fiiiiine *-edits-* :P

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange is great for specific answers to specific problems: critiquing or reviewing people's work doesn't lend itself well to the format, and if I recall correctly, it's off-topic almost everywhere except [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com).

If there's something you'd like to get help understanding, feel free to ask that question, though: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if code, [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) if more high-level, conceptual stuff.